# Convert PHP array values from string to integer

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer

I am new to PHP. I used curl and regex to get all the number with a certain pattern from an HTML table like this:

```
preg_match_all("/<td>[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}<\/td>/m",$result,$match);
print_r($match);
```

This is the result array: ($match)

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10.00 [1] => 10.00 [2] => 10.00 [3] => 1.00 [4] => 12.00 ) )

All the values are strings, I need them as integers. How to do that?
I tried this solution, but it gives 0 as an integer (was 10.00). Is it because it's an array inside array?

```
$test = $match[0][1];
$test2 = (int)$test;
echo $test2
```

Comment: have you tried using intval() instead?

Comment: Please try to use foreach() to loop through the array

Comment: tried it now also gives 0    $test2 = intval($test);

Comment: use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format) or [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) examples: https://3v4l.org/VdTav

Comment: Group `0` contains the HTML so it can't be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a capture group for just the number. See:

```
preg_match_all("/<td>([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2})<\/td>/",'<td>10.00</td><td>22.33</td>',$matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
    echo (int)$match; 
}
```

See https://3v4l.org/kL6rp

Although you are seeing:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10.00 [1] => 10.00 [2] => 10.00 [3] => 1.00 [4] => 12.00 ) )
```

Your array really has HTML still in it, so it is:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => <td>10.00</td> [1] => <td>10.00</td> [2] => <td>10.00</td> [3] => <td>1.00</td> [4] => <td>12.00</td> ) )
```

casting that to an int won't work. So capturing the inner value via regex is a better approach. Alternatively `strip_tags` could be used.

Comment: 1022 is not correct its taking `10` from `10.00` and `22` from `22.33`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That's from my example because I didnt put a new line. That should be correct if OP wants ints, not floats.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The dup doesn't match the question. OP is trying to cast a string with HTML

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to simply convert the string to a number, i.e `10.00`, not `10`, nor `1022`

Comment: i see so now I understand why it wasn't working. thanks for showing me the problem i will try a different approach.